# Entity Framework not using updated connection string

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework-6, database-connection

Is it possible to change the connection string within the app.config file and have Entity Framework start using the new values?

I have a multi-threaded app with one thread acting as the dispatcher.  This thread has the ability to receive a message telling it to change all or part of the connection string data (such as a password change). It then updates the config file to include the new connection information and clears any pooled database connections.  This part is all working correctly.

The problem is, when the dispatcher launches a new thread and this thread creates a new database context the database connection is created with the old connection string values.  It appears Entity Framework is keeping a cached copy of this information somewhere.  If I completely shutdown and restart the app it works correctly because it, obviously, has to read the new values from the config file.

I have seen other proposed solutions involving keeping the connection string as a variable and passing it to the context constructor.  But since the dispatcher thread has no internal knowledge of the "job" threads it creates (some may not even require database access) this won't really work for me.  At least not without a lot of code changes and special requirements of my job interface.

This is the code I'm using to update the file.  As I said, this part is working.  Is there something else I need to do to tell Entity Framework about the change?

```
 // Create new connection string

 SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[CONNECTION_STRING_NAME].ConnectionString);
 connectionBuilder.DataSource = server;
 connectionBuilder.InitialCatalog = database;
 connectionBuilder.UserID = user;
 connectionBuilder.Password = password;

 // Update connection string within config file

 Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
 ConnectionStringsSection section = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
 section.ConnectionStrings[CONNECTION_STRING_NAME].ConnectionString = connectionBuilder.ToString();

 // Save changes

 ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
 config.Save();
```

Comment: It reads the config file when it first starts, you'd have to restart whatever it is you're running to pick up config changes (website, windows app etc.). `At least not without a lot of code changes` - might not be what you want to hear - but I'd say I'd try and avoid this ever-changing config approach anyway, the config file's not really to be used for that (ideally!). As you've already read, I would suggest injecting the connection string, possibly leveraging some IoC to keep it all neat and tidy.

Comment: if you have access to all contexts, then closing connection and doing myDbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = newConnectionString; should work. I have not checked though.

Comment: @Arie, thanks but this doesn't seem to help. Each process creates their own context instance within a "using" statement so they are created and destroyed fairly regularly.  Even though they are all of the same subtype changing the connection string on one doesn't seem to impact the others.

Comment: Which `DbContext` constructor overload is used?

Comment: I'm using the one that specifies the connection string name

Comment: The problem is that EF6 caches `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`, so `RefreshSection` has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) method does say (emphasis is mine):

> Refreshes the named section **so the next time that it is retrieved** it will be re-read from disk.

The problem is that EF6 caches the [`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings?view=netframework-4.7.2) in an internal class static property, so it never gets refreshed.

Unfortunately there is no "official" way to refresh it. Following is a brute force hack using reflection, so use it on your own risk:

```
static readonly Type EF6AppConfigType = typeof(DbContext).Assembly.GetType("System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig");

static readonly PropertyInfo EF6DefaultAppConfig = EF6AppConfigType.GetProperty("DefaultInstance", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

static readonly FieldInfo EF6ConnectionStrings = EF6AppConfigType.GetField("_connectionStrings", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

static void RefreshEF6ConnectionStrings()
{
    EF6ConnectionStrings.SetValue(
        EF6DefaultAppConfig.GetValue(null),
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
    );
}
```

Just call it after saving the changes:

```
config.Save();
RefreshEF6ConnectionStrings();
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivan Stoev, I really appreciate all of the help.  But you're right, that looks a little risky.